# joomla with multiple line translation

Tags: translation, joomla1.5

i am developing a joomla 1.5 module and don't know how to make a multiple row translation file

in my file **en-gb.com_abc.ini**

i have:

```
TITLE=Title
AUTH LINK=Authorization Link
CONTRACT=this is a very long translation
and i need it on more than one row
is it possible?
```

when i use `echo JText::_('CONTRACT');`
joomla only outputs

```
this is a very long translation
```

but i would like it to ouput

```
this is a very long translation
and i need it on more than one row
is it possible?
```

how to do it ?

Comment: did you try to use "\n" for a new row?

Comment: \n works, except i would like it to be in a human friendly format, to allow other people to be able to edit the language file -> the contract document, otherwise, once encoded this way, it would be one looong line...

Answer (score 1):

put "" around the text or put '\n' at the end of each line.

Comment: i think the comment from Thor should be for max4ever (look at the date) but his solution may be the correct answer

Comment: See what you mean, and it seems to have solved his problem. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

in joomla 1.5 "" doesn't work, the only solution i found was writing a script which replaces all "\r\n" with

"\\n"